# TEZ doesn't work when tez.lib.uris==tez.tar.gz

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, ambari, apache-tez

I installed Tez 0.9.1 via Ambari 2.6.1. tez.tar.gz is successfully copped to hdfs. But while service check - I get error. Diving into logs by `yarn logs -applicationId APP_ID` I found `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster`. though DAG jar is in tar.gz. tez.lib.uris==${fs.default.name}/hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/tez/tez.tar.gz. If I untar it right into hdfs and change: `tez.lib.uris==${fs.default.name}/hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/tez,${fs.default.name}/hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/tez/lib` everything works fine, service check is OK. 
Tried: manually copping tar.gz, setting chmod 777 to it, various tez.lib.uris.classpath values - nothing works.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: This happens, because tar.gz is not being uncompressed! But description says that `Specifying a single .tar.gz or .tgz assumes that a compressed version of the tez libs is being used. This is uncompressed into a tezlibs directory when running containers, and tezlibs/;tezlibs/lib/ are added to the classpath (after . and .*).` but this doesn't happen. why?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. 
Need to extend yarn.application.classpath in yarn-site.xml with: `/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/lib/*`
In the end value in my case is:

```
{{hadoop_home}}/conf,{{hadoop_home}}/*,{{hadoop_home}}/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*,/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/tez-client/lib/*
```